# Preview the title when asking a question

Tags: feature-request

When asking a question, only the body of the text is shown in the preview below the window where one enters the text.
It would be nice to have the title of the question included in the preview, such that it can be debugged easier too.

Could this be done or are there technical and / or other reasons that make such an extension of the preview for questions not feasable ?

Comment: A good suggestion, but as it affects network-wide behavior it should be on the [on the mother meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115247/please-include-the-title-in-the-question-preview).

Comment: Thanks @dmckee for the link to the other MSO question. The single answer there is not very satisfying but even so my question would have been a doublicate over there ...

Comment: No, I don't much like Jeff's answer either. But the usual situation applies....the team is very busy, they prioritizes thing and they don't always agree with the users. And six to eight weeks. And so on.

Comment: I have mentioned this question here (on [meta.se]): [Show a preview of the title when editing/asking - at least on the MathJax sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/361217).